# Как объединить 2 массива в bs4

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'xxxx'
response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
quotes = bs.find_all('td', class_='row3 over')
 #print(quotes)

for item2 in quotes:
    item2_text = item2.text
    qw = item2.text
     #print(qw)

#for link in bs.find_all('a'):

 #   print(link.get('href'))

all_a = bs.find_all('a', class_='last-post-icon')

 #print(all_a)

for item in all_a:
    item_text = item.text
    item_url = item.get("href")
    print(f'{qw}: {item_url}')
```

По задумке, код должен каждые 2 секунды парсить страницу, потом заносить результат формата "title_name + url" в какой то список. Проблема с выводом сообщений из переменных.

Переменная qw имеет, допустим 10 названий топиков = title
Переменная item_url имеет ссылку на последнее сообщение = url

При попытке их распечатать выдается список формата:

```
title1 : url 1
title1 : url 2
title1 : url 3
```

Как их совместить таким образом, чтобы сохранить очередность из каждой переменной?

```
title1 : url 1
title2 : url 2
title3 " url 3
```

Comment: Посмотрите как ТУТ решается https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101617/beautifulsoup-retrieve-the-text-of-all-childs-a-tag-of-tds-tags

Comment: zip(quotes, all_a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае так:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
quotes = bs.find_all('td', class_='row3 over')
all_a = bs.find_all('a', class_='last-post-icon')
for item, item2 in zip(all_a, quotes):
    qw = item2.text
    item_url = item.get("href")
    print(f'{qw}: {item_url}')
```

А если скинете ссылку на сайт я вам напишу еще один вариант кода